# Does ActionMailer only render views when methods are invoked on its explicit class name? (i.e. not "self")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm noticing very strange behavior on my CustomMailer (subclass of ActionMailer):

```
class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def deliver(template) # with ":greeting" passed as argument

    # WORKS: Renders view app/views/custom_mailer/greeting
    CustomMailer.send(template)

    # BROKEN: Does not render view app/view/custom_mailer/greeting
    self.send(template)
  end

  def greeting # this gets called by both invocations, but
               # only the former renders the view. Why?
    ...
    mail(to: ...
```

Why does the first one render but not the second one? Here are my hypotheses:

- `send` can't be invoked on `self` without causing shenanigans
- the crazy magic that allows ActionMailer to render a view (from what is almost a model) relies on targeting methods that are invoked on CustomMailer explicitly
- [update] something about `self` and instance methods vs. CustomMailer and class methods?

Answer (score 0):

ActionMailer::Base [overloads the class' method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3fbc042b580f518d060671d0dd86ec2a4d14a42b/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L434) and instead creates an instance, and eventually calls the instance method and/or renders the view.

Comment: So invoking self.send(template) isn't invoking on the instance? But because "ActionMailer::Base overloads the class' method_missing", that means CustomMailer.send(template) is invoking on the instance?